# React js overwriting CSS sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having trouble converting this example code to a React JS format. Here is the example in codepen, https://codepen.io/WebDevSimplified/pen/LqKQRK. My structure is very similar if not the same for both the html and css code.

I have a navbar with some responsiveness in the css style sheet.

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .navbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This toggle function shows and hides the navbar div.

```
toggle() {
    this.setState({displayMenu: !this.state.displayMenu});
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = this.state.displayMenu ? "flex" : "none";
    console.log(this.state.displayMenu);
}
```

However, upon using the toggle function the css responsiveness no longer works. Why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do. I recommend you to edit the question and share your relevant react code.

Comment: Does your toggle function check every time the screen size change? Does it update the component state?

Comment: @CodeTech It doesn't. I was just trying to figure out why the css doesn't reset when I change the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update this problem I used a new approach. Instead of changing the display style manually in the toggle function I altered the id of the div. This way the id only applied when the screen was a certain size.

`<div className="navbar-links" id={this.state.display ? "show" : ""}>`

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .navbar-links#show {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React component, you better use the state to hide and show your component.

Look at the following source: "[How to Show and Hide ReactJS Components](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-show-and-hide-reactjs-components)".

By reading again your code, I believe you need to be careful about React async function. React is based on JavaScript so a lot of things are async when you use JavaScript.

In your toggle function, you use `setState(this.state.displayMenu)` although it won't get an immediate update after you do Document.

My suggestion is you do:

```
this.setState(this.state.displayMenu, () => { 
  document.getElementById("menu").style.display = this.state.displayMenu ? "flex" : "none"; 
})
```

see if it changes

Comment: Should post what the link is about in case the link were to ever rot. Answers shouldnt rely on external sources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would take it into account next time. I am quite a new user of this platform, I usually just read people stacks.

Comment: Think of it this way. The best answers are ones that someone can just read the Q&A and the answer doesn't rely on a user going back and forth to an external link. Samples or multiple samples, references and actual run cases (when an external link to a sandbox would be ok) helps increase your chance of someone up voting.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to use state. You can get the example code as inspiration and instead of using `addEventListener`, just pass a `toggle` function as the `onClick` attribute of `.toggle-button`:

```js
function toggle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0].classList.toggle('active');
};

ReactDOM.render(      
  <nav className="navbar">
    <div className="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
    <a
      href="#"
      className="toggle-button"
      onClick={toggle}
    >Menu</a>
    <div className="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.navbar-links {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-links.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```